# ¿Cómo mostrar un mensaje alert (Javascript) en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Hola amigos necesito de su ayuda por favor, ya se que esta pregunta es repetida pero a mi no me sale, no se porque, tengo problemas con hacer un alert dentro de mis etiquetas PHP, Ya intente de muchas formas y no me sale , por lo menos me podrías identificar mi error, o sugerirme otras soluciones. Gracias

Este es mi Código:

```
else{
    //Mis intento fallidos
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">'; echo 'alert("Error al crear sugerencia")'; echo '</script>';
    echo'<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Tarea Guardada");</script>';
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"Error al crear sugerencia\");</script>"; 
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("Error al crear sugerencia");</script>'; 
    echo '<script language="javascript">alert("'.$id.'");</script>';

    $arrResult['error'] = "No fue posible la inserción. Error:  ".$conexion->error;

    //Cómo puedo meter variables y que me muestren el contenido
    $saludo = "hola";
    echo "<script>alert('". $conexion->error ."');</script>";

    header("location: ../ubicacion_profesiografico.php");
    include_once('../ubicacion_profesiografico.php'); 
}
```

Comment: Hola, a modo de sugerencia, te recomiendo usar una estructura de programación mas simple y mucho mas ordenada, utilizando un Cliente (Javascript, JQuery, Ajax, o el de mi preferencia Angular) y el Backend (puede ser PHP). Te ayuda a tener mas ordenado tu codigo y a entenderlo mejor, además de que es una mejor practica mostrar el Alert desde el lado del Cliente.

Comment: El código PHP me parece familiar y si mal no recuerdo de se trata de una petición Ajax que mandas al servidor. Si es así, como ha dicho @jecorrales lo mejor es mostrar el `alert` **del lado del cliente**, o sea, desde el `done` o el `success`  de la petición Ajax. No es buena la mezcla que intentas hacer aquí. Pon todo en `$arrResult`,  devuélvelo al cliente como un JSON  y en el cliente lee ese JSON y muestra los mensajes, alertas redirecciones que hagan falta. Cuando el código de servidor termina con su trabajo conviene que lo dejes tranquilo, devolviendo los datos al cliente.

Comment: @A.Cedano excelente, es bueno verte por acá muy seguido. Eres un gran apoyo para la comunidad y sobre todo de que aprendo en cada comentario o respuesta que dejas por cada pregunta que se realiza.

Comment: Gracias @jecorrales por tu amable comentario. Aprovecho el espacio que me queda en este comentario para añadir que cuando digo *poner todo en `$arrResult`* no me refiero a los `alert` y demás. Ese código fue dado en una respuesta precisamente con la intención de recoger en `$arrResult` todo lo que pueda ocurrir durante la ejecución en el servidor. Luego sería cuestión de  leer en el `done` los elementos del JSON devuelto. Si por ejemplo el mismo tiene una clave `error` mostrar un mensaje o redirigir a otra parte, y si no tiene una clave `error` hacer otra cosa. Esa es la idea de `$arrResult`.

Comment: Tienen razón amigos gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 4):

Así es como se ejecuta un alert de javascript desde php.
Por ejemplo, crea una variable con un texto, para ver que se pueden añadir variables al alert de javascript desde php.

```
$var = "Hola Pepe";
echo "<script> alert('".$var."'); </script>";
```

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad porque no suelen ser de ayuda para otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que sugieres y cómo soluciona el problema. Lee [answer] para más información y completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla). Un saludo.

Comment: Con esta explicación/descripción ¿está mejor?

Answer (score 0):

sencillamente de la siguiente manera:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Data has been submitted to ' . $to . '");</script>';
```

aunque no es recomendable hacerlo asi.

actualizacion:

```
 echo '<script">alert("Data has been submitted to ' . $to . '");</script>';
```

investigue un poco porque me comentaron que no era necesario el tipo en javascript yo recomardaba que desde la  version 5 de html ya viene por default pero no era asi desde hace mucho desde  la version 2 de Netscape ya no es necesaria porque viene por default como lenguage en los browser, es necesaria pero no es obligatoria.

[es necesaria el tipo en la extension en javascript? (en ingles
)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags)

Comment: El type no es necesario

Comment: lose que en HTTML5 ya no es necesario poner  type="text/javascript" pero por la  costumbre siembre la pongo, pero igualmente te recomiendo leer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706290/why-write-script-type-text-javascript-when-the-mime-type-is-set-by-the-serve y  https://www.quora.com/Is-it-necessary-to-add-src-text-JavaScript-in-script-tag

Comment: Desde antes de HTML 5 no era necesario

Comment: ah ya veo , investigue un poco y encontre que desde Netscape 2 no es necesaria que ya viene por default en los browsers , aqui lo leei: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar las comillas simples para que no tengas problema con las dobles

```
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Tarea Guardada");
window.location.href="index.php";
</script>';
```

Answer (score 0):

¿has probado a salir de código php?
Digamos:

```
?><script> alert("mensaje <?php echo $id; ?>");</script><?php
```

Prueba a ver que tal esa opción, a veces los juegos de comillas en los echo dan problemas en algunas versiones de PHP o dependiendo de la configuración del servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Todos tus alert son correctos, sin embargo.
Creo que tienes el enfoque equivocado:

- En el servidor php se encarga de ejecutar tu codigo y generar al final un archivo "compilado por asi desirlo", al final el servidor de archivos proporciona al navegador en tu caso es tu HTML + Javascript, el cual termina ejecutando en el navegador tu código Javascript y renderando tu HTML.
- Si lo que estas intentando es a través de una petición Ajax la respuesta es texto plano por lo cual en el cliente (navegadaor) deveras obtener ese texto y tal ves ejecutarlo con un eval().